# Cocos2dx v3 Problem with moving Sprite on tilemap after it was scrolled up

Tags: tilemap, cocos2d-x

I have a problem I can't solve so far.
I have a scene with tile map on it. And there is a Sprite spawnpoint on map. This Sprite should do MoveTo() action to the point where TouchEnded().

It all works perfectly in the borders of the screen, but after I scroll my map up and do touch again my Sprite stuck in the max Y point of the screen. (Let's say there is max 480px of screen's Y, but 850px of tile map)

Please help!

Comment: Could you include the code that's causing the problem?